# Visual Studio files renamed on Save

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, microsoft-distributed-file-system

We are having an issue where when files are saved through Visual Studio to our server farm occasionally the aspx files get completely renamed to something like this "hi2zsnk2.hvc~". The web farm is windows based using DFS. The server guys are blaming Visual Studio I think it is DFS that is causing the issue. I haven't been able to find anything on the web where anyone else talks about Visual Studio renaming files. Has anyone else had this issue with Visual Studio? Thanks for any help.

We are just direct saving and not publishing.

Comment: Considering adding an extra tag like aspx --- it may be difficult for someone who knows about the subject to notice this.  The tag of "visual-studio" is pretty broad.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added dfs and asp.net to it. Thanks.